# How to log info in flask?

Tags: html, python-3.x, logging, flask

I am using pythonanywhere.com to run my code ,
I am using a post form in the index.html and I have a log.txt file and I want to log the info ip address of the user and below that I want the post form .
https://ibb.co/esiJhJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get IP address from `request.remote_addr` and using python default `logging` library you can easily write the ip into a file.

**code example**

```
import logging

from flask import request

# configure your logging and let the file name is text.log
logging.basicConfig(filename='text.log', 
                    level=logging.INFO)


@app.route("/your_path", methods=["POST"])
def example():
    logging.info("ip: {}".format(request.remote_addr))
```

you can also modify the write format. For more details visit [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)